# Prevent HighlightPainter from overriding selection color in Java

Tags: java, highlight

I'm using a `HighlightPainter` to change the background color of a chunk of text within a JTextArea like this:

```
HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.Yellow);
textarea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(i, j, painter);
```

It works, but the new highlighter overrides the selection color such that there is no selection displayed in the highlit part (from `i` to `j`). (By selection I mean what you do when you want to Copy/Paste text.)

Am I using it wrong - and how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a simple solution is to use a transparent color for the highlighter, i.e., adapt the "a"-value of the color when using, for example, the "rgba" constructor.